# Chrome extension authentication with twitter facebook google etc

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension

I'm implementing a chrome extension and will make use of facebook, twitter and google oauth for login. I've searched for the topic but haven't found the good example, integration module yet. If anyone can recommend a module to use or a place to look, please let me know

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an official [OAuth 1.0 library](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) for chrome extensions here:

As well an experimental [OAuth 2.0 library](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions).

Comment: Thanks, But what about security? If I make a popup with a backgroundpage and uses oauth. Then I need secrects and so on in the requests. But will this not be possible to see for every one viewing the source of the extension or is the background page hidden?

Comment: This library got deprecated. New way is here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity